# How can my anchor balise stop where my <p> item stops

Tags: html, css

I have a grid for my footer. I would like to know if there is a way that only the text of my footer would be a link, and not the whole column each time.
Thanks.

```css
footer {
  margin-top: 65px;
  background: #F2F2F2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer-cont">
    <a class="footer-lien" href="">
      <h3 class="footer-item">À propos</h3>
    </a>
    <a class="footer-lien" href="">
      <p class="footer-item">Fonctionnement du site</p>
    </a>
    <a class="footer-lien" href="">
      <p class="footer-item">Conditions générales</p>
    </a>
    <a class="footer-lien" href="">
      <p class="footer-item">Données et confidentialité</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="footer-cont">
    <a class="footer-lien" href="">
      <h3 class="footer-item">Nos hébergements</h3>
    </a>
    <a class="footer-lien" href="">
      <p class="footer-item">Charte qualité</p>
    </a>
    <a class="footer-lien" href="">
      <p class="footer-item">Proposer votre hôtel</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="footer-cont">
    <a class="footer-lien" href="">
      <h3 class="footer-item">Assistance</h3>
    </a>
    <a class="footer-lien" href="">
      <p class="footer-item">Centre d'aider</p>
    </a>
    <a class="footer-lien" href="">
      <p class="footer-item">Nous contacter</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

[image: my footer]

Comment: Put the `a` elements inside the `p`/`h3` elements instead of the other way around.

Comment: You can't put block-level elements inside of inline-level elements. `<p class="footer-item"><a class="footer-lien" href="">Nous contacter</a></p>`

Comment: @TimR an anchor is a special case. An anchor can contain block-level elements nowadays.

Comment: If you don't want something to be a link, don't wrap it with an `<a>` element.